# Https issue with a java web app running on apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, https

I'm having regarding a java web app running on apache.

One of the pages is invoking an applet which code is an external server.

The company responsible of the applet told us to use HTTPS when invoking the page showing the applet as we had problems when we invoked the page using HTTP.

The problem is that when I browse the page in HTTPS , I have an ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error.

The address I want to browse looks like :

https://www.myurl.com:8084/myWebApp/pageContainingApplet.jsp?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2

I looked for the server.xml file under /conf and added this tag:

```
<Connector port="8084" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Still nothing

Answer (score 0):

**Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long**

This usually means the implementation of SSL on your server is not correct. The error is usually caused by a server side problem which the server administrator will need to investigate. Below are some things we recommend trying.

- Ensure that port 443 is open and enabled on your server. This is the 
  standard port for https communications.
- If SSL is using a non-standard port then FireFox 3 can sometimes give
  this error. Ensure SSL is running on port 443.
- If using Apache2 check that you are using port 443 for SSL. This can
  be done by setting the ports.conf file as follows
- Listen 80 Listen 443 https Make sure you do not have more than one
  SSL certificate sharing the same IP. Please ensure that all SSL
  certificates utilise their own dedicated IP.
- If using Apache2 check your vhost config. Some users have reported
  changing  to *default* resolved the error.
- Make sure that your SSL certificate is not expired
- Try to specify the Cipher:

  SSLCipherSuite
  ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+SSLv3

Also check this : https://support.servertastic.com/error-code-ssl-error-rx-record-too-long/